# How to render a jQuery mobile checkbox within a knockout foreach loop?

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I seem to be having difficulties rendering a standard jQuery checkbox when I am inside a knockout foreach loop.

It looks fine using standard code like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-theme="c" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" data-bind="checked: error, click: acceptChanges" />
<label for="checkbox-1">Error</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-theme="c" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2" class="custom" data-bind="checked: information, click: acceptChanges" />
<label for="checkbox-2">Information</label>
```

But when I try this within a foreach loop it renders very small!

```
<!-- ko foreach: selectedLogTypes -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-theme="c" class="custom" 
            data-bind="jqmChecked: isSelected, attr: { 'id': 'checkbox_' + $index(), 'name': 'checkbox_' + $index() }" />
        <label data-bind="text: logType, attr: { 'for': 'checkbox_' + $index() }"></label>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here is the link to a fiddle sample demonstrating the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/mheere/A33Ng/1/

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enhance `checkbox` and `controlgroup` manually.

```
$("[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();
$("[data-role=controlgroup]").controlgroup();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bHLpC/)**